# How to make an already existing regular expression case-insensitive?

Tags: regex, perl, case-insensitive

How can I make a regular expression **which was already compiled** case-insensitive in Perl?

```
my $regex = qr/b/;
if ( 'aBc' =~ $regex ) { print "matches\n" }
```

This doesn't work:

```
$regex = qr/$regex/i;
```

Nor this:

```
$regex = "(?i:$regex)";
```

Nor this

```
$regex = "(?i)$regex";
```

Comment: try `$regex = "(?i)"."$regex";`